# Threejs subdivided plane geometry huge fps drop

Tags: three.js

I'm adding 3 buffered plane geometries to the scene. They are 400x300, and subdivided the same amount.

Now my issue is that when I add them to the scene, my FPS drops from 60 to 1. I didn't expect such an fps drop. Are there any optimizations I can do to improve the performance? (I need the subdivisions for applying a heightmap later on)

Comment: 1FPS seems very low, but a drop is a normal behaviour with this number of vertices. You have 3* 120,000, that begins to be much for low-middle range computers. I've reproduced what you describe in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5L4hheL/), do you experience the same FPS drop to 1 fps ?

Comment: @Atrahasis Interesting, I don't get the FPS drop in that fiddle. Would it have anything to do with the texture I'm using with the material?

Comment: It depends of the rest of your code then,  I can't tell more without it

Comment: With no further info it's hard to say but a common culprit is transparency with multiple layers. Are you using texture alpha?

Comment: @bjorke Are there any optimizations I can do related to the transparency layers?

Comment: Obvious optimization: don't do that. Seriously: as an experiment, turn off transparency entirely, see what happens to your frame rate. Now you know the upper limit of your potential improvements.

Less-obvious optimization: make sure you're not drawing large areas of completeley "empty" pixels by shaping you geometry to look more like the shape of the non-transparent texture

Comment: make sure you are not building geometry in the loop. Make the geometry in the init method and add to scene.
this happen when you are adding object into the scene in the loop i.e. requestAnimationFrame

Comment: @Stallion I'm making it in the init then adding it